# how to make button stay in the same box?

Tags: css

I create a button but whenever I make my windows smaller the button is out of my box. It doesn't look nice. I was wondering how can I make my button to stay in the box. See pictures to have a better understanding. 
I provided the CSS of my button. I'm not sure how to implement a good and efficient solution for this problem.
I was able to fix my problem by changing width to 100%. Now my letter are getting cut off from my botton. See picture please!

[image: Full Screen]

[image: Half size of screen]

[image: Letter are getting cut off]

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
// margin: 5px;
 padding: 0 22px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
 height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
 line-height: 40px;
 background-color: #428bca;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 border: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;

}
.panel-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-heading {

    color: #428bca;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
   border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;  
    //border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    //border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.nobottommargin {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.leftmargin-sm {
    margin-left: 30px !important;
}

.button.button-rounded {
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.button.button-reveal {
 padding: 0 28px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.button.button-large {
 padding: 0 26px;
 font-size: 16px;
 height: 46px;
 line-height: 46px;
}

.button-teal {
 background-color: #428bca;
}

/*code for the icon */
.button-reveal i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}
.button-reveal:hover i {
  left: 0;
}
/* code for the letters*/
.button-reveal span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
  transition: margin 0.35s ease;
}
.button-reveal:hover span {
  margin: 0 1em 0 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">Access This Service</h2>
       </div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <!-- angular -->
   
  <div ng-if="c.html" ng-bind-html="c.html"></div>

 <a href="http://zoom.us" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span>Go there now!</span></a><br>

Note: If you haven’t accessed Zoom before, create a new account at <a href="http://zoom.us">zoom.us</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your css?

Comment: try adding style='width:100%;' to the button

Comment: Going to need to see the relevant html & css for this, it should be part of the question. This way people can reproduce your example.

Comment: Where’s the HTML?

Comment: change the width to 100% instead of 220px

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100%;` and reduce the `font-size` if needed. You're probably seeing the overflow because of the fixed width and `padding`.

Comment: Why do I need to add box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100%; ???  Do I need to get rid of the padding?

Answer (score 1):

```
.button {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding within the button's width */
    width: 100%; /* Made the button the full width of its parent */
    padding: 0 22px; /* Add 22 pixels of padding to the left and right of the button */
}
```

You probably don't need the padding, so you could just do:

```
button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is it 100%? And another quick question what does the padding 0 20px do? Thanks again!

Comment: it will adding padding to the left & right of the button

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. The problem that I am facing now id that whenever I make my window smaller, my letters "GO THERE NOW" are getting cut off.

Comment: Remove `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

The padding is pushing the the text to the right and the 'white-space: nowrap' is preventing the text from wrapping to a second line.  Your text is too wide for the space when you make the div narrow, so it has to go somewhere. If you allow it to wrap, it will occupy two lines when the width is too narrow. Set 'min-height' instead of 'height' so the button can expand.

```
button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    //height: 40px; 
    min-height: 40px;
    white-space: normal;

}
```

Comment: If you could post the HTML it would be a lot easier to help you. I cannot test my solution otherwise.

Comment: I just added the html